# Can the Bolt "Simple Forms" extension be used to send data?

Tags: php, email, bolt-cms

My Bolt site lists a lot of events. Can I use the Simple Forms extension to email a list of events to a visitor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but I would advise against it - a better way would be to use a real mailinglist (mailchimp or campaignmonitor are great for mailinglists)

The problem is that you create an open relay for spambots with a simpleform that is used as a place to send anyone mail - it is meant to be used as a contact form where visitors can send messages to the site owner

If you still want to use it to send visitors a list of events - you can look at the "use_as" parameter for emailfields in the documentation.